# Increase Animation Speed Win2d line UWP

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp, win2d

I would like to increase the animation speed of the line by keeping the step 1.

**Xaml:**

```
    <canvas:CanvasAnimatedControl x:Name="canvas" 
                                  Margin="0,30,0,0"
                                  Height="500"
                                  Draw="OnDraw"/>
```

**cs:**

```
    private bool _adding = true;
    private int _Offset = 0;

    private void OnDraw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        CanvasDrawingSession ds = args.DrawingSession;

        double height = sender.Size.Height;
        double width = sender.Size.Width;

        var point1 = new Vector2((float)(width / 2), (float)height);
        var point2 = new Vector2((float)(width / 2), (float)height - (float)_Offset);

        CanvasSolidColorBrush brush = new CanvasSolidColorBrush(sender, Colors.Green);

        ds.DrawLine(point1, point2, brush, (float)10);
        if (_adding)
        {
            _Offset++;
        }
        else
        {
            _Offset--;
        }
        if (_Offset == 0 || _Offset == 300)
        {
            _adding = !_adding;
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to keep the _offset step at 1 but increase the line animation speed and to keep TargetElapsedTime at 16?

Comment: Currently I haven't found a solution yet, but I'll continue to try it.

Comment: Logically, you need to increase the offset. If you want it to continue running every 16ms, your only option is to do *more* on every run.